# List files sorted according to specific line of contents

Tags: files, sort

I have a directory of files. There is a line in each file that says:

```
# order: N
```

where N is an integer number. I want to list all files in the directory (or even include them in wrapper script) according to that N number. Is this possible from a bash command-line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU `grep`, and assuming file names don't contain colon or newline characters:

```
$ ls
bar     baz     foo     freeble quux
$ cat ./*
# order: 3
# order: 2
# order: 1
# order: 4
# order: 5
$ grep -m1 -EH '^# order: [0-9]+$' ./* | sort -n -k3 | cut -d: -f1
foo
baz
bar
freeble
quux
```

Comment: Better use `grep -H`, otherwise it won't work if there is only one file.

Comment: Good catch.  Done.

Answer (score 2):

With single GNU **`awk`** process:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc" }
     /order: [0-9]+/{ a[FILENAME]=$NF; nextfile }
     END{ for(i in a) print i }' ./*
```

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`, you can define a glob sorting order based on the content of those lines with:

```
byOrder() REPLY=$(grep '^# order:' < $REPLY)
```

and then use it for example with:

```
printf '%s\n' *(.no+byOrder)
```

or

```
sorted_file_list=(*(.no+byOrder))
```

(also adding a `.` to the glob qualifier to only consider *regular* files (not directories, fifos, symlinks...)).